# Uso de los módulos en TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, es6

Intento exportar e importar módulos en TypeScript, pero a la hora de mostrar el código en el navegador aparece lo siguiente:

> ReferenceError: exports is not defined
>
> ---
>
> ReferenceError: require is not defined

**Código:**

```
**script.js**
let num:number = 5;
export {num as numberVar};

**script2.js**
import { numberVar } from "./script";

let showImport: (num: number) => void =
    function(num:number){
    console.log(num);
};

showImport(numberVar);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="script2.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No estás pasando ese código por un transpiler antes de verlo en un navegador?

Comment: No, soy nuevo en esto de TypeScript, si he leido que los navegadores aún no tienen implementado esto de los modulos nativamente pero no se como implementarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Instala el transpilador de Typescript, via npm: `npm install ntypescript -g`.

Luego en consola, dirigete hacia el directorio donde tienes tus archivos de typescript y ejecuta `ntsc`. Recuerda renombrar la extension de tus archivos `.js` a `.ts`.

[Aqui](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ntypescript) hay mas informacion acerca del uso del transpilador de typescript y [aca](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) te enseñan a usar el archivo de configuracion de compilacion.

Si usas algun editor que use paquetes y dependencias de la comunidad busca si tiene algun paquete para la compilacion de typescript en tiempo real.

Es cuestion de leer Internet y probar, hay mucha informacion disponible.

Comment: Ya tenia instalado el trasnpilador e inclusive el webstorm que es el IDE que utilizo viene con uno incluido pero sigue mostrando el mismo error en consola el navegador.